# How to change code from PandasRollingOLS to just RollingOLS?

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I'm working my way through this book - https://github.com/stefan-jansen/machine-learning-for-trading/blob/c7e508dbe98e064887faeca65a45966e85af1c96/04_alpha_factor_research/01_feature_engineering.ipynb

It looks like it uses a deprecated version of PandasRollingOLS in this line of code -
`from statsmodels.regression.rolling import PandasRollingOLS`

It's later referenced here -
`T = 24 betas = (factor_data .groupby(level='ticker', group_keys=False) .apply(lambda x: RollingOLS(window=min(T, x.shape[0]-1), y=x.return_1m, x=x.drop('return_1m', axis=1)).beta))`

I was hoping someone could tell me how I could convert this line of code to use. -
`statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingOLS`

Answer (score 0):

There aren't too many changes needed.  You can use this in place of the corresponding cell in the original notebook:

```
from statsmodels.api import add_constant
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS

T = 24
# Variables excluding "const"
keep=["Mkt-RF","SMB","HML","RMW","CMA"]

betas = (add_constant(factor_data)  # Add the constant
         .groupby(level='ticker', group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: RollingOLS(window=min(T, x.shape[0]-1), endog=x.return_1m, exog=x.drop('return_1m', axis=1)).fit().params[keep]))
```

The changes:

1. Import `RollingOLS` and `add_constant`
2. Get the list of betas to retain. We don't want `const` which is added by `add_constant`
3. Call the same group by only using `RollingOLS`.  Rename `y` to `endog` and `x` to `exog`.
4. You need to explicitly call `fit()` on `RollingOLS`.
5. Access the coefficients using `params`, and use `keep` to retain the relevant ones.

Comment: The issue I was having was finding the code for PandasRollingOLS. Where were you able to find the syntax to be able to figure out what needed to be changed?

Comment: The function is here: https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance/blob/c95925209a809b4e648e79cbeaf7711d8e5ff1a6/pyfinance/ols.py#L343